# Perl dereference on args cannot be used in comparison, but copy of it can

Tags: perl

I have read some arguments at the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.0360;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':default';
use Devel::Confess 'color';
use Getopt::ArgParse;

my $parser = Getopt::ArgParse->new_parser(
    help        => 'This script finds and pretty-prints a line within a CSV file', 
);
$parser-> add_args(
    ['-file',  '-f', required => 1, type => 'Scalar'],
    ['-regex', '-r', required => 1, type => 'Scalar'], # regex pattern within each line
    ['-sep' ,  '-s', required => 0, type => 'Scalar']
);
my $args =  $parser->parse_args(@ARGV);
my $sep = $args->sep // ',';
my $regex = $args->regex;
my @header;
say $args->regex;
open my $fh, '<', $args->file;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if ($. == 1) {
        @header = split $sep;
        next
    }
    next unless /$regex/; # key point
    say __LINE__;
#   code later
}
```

the problem here is that the regex comparison

`next unless /$regex/`

works, but

`next unless /$args->regex/`

does not work, even though the two are copies of each other via `my $regex = $args->regex;`

Strangely, I can use `$args->file` but cannot use `$args->regex`

Why does `$args->regex` work like this?  What is the correct terminology for `$args->regex`? It's not a hash, it's some sort of object.

Comment: Btw, instead of testing every line of the file whether it's the first (`$. == 1`) you can first read the first line, `my @header = split $sep, <$fh>;` and then read on (`$fh` has moved), `while (<$fh>) { } #from second line`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't interpolate method calls into a string. I guarantee you that `$args->file` doesn't work either here. Note that `$args->regex` is not a field access but a method call, equivalent to `$args->regex()`.

When interpolating a variable into a quote-like context (including regexes), you can use scalars, arrays, and array/hash field accesses.

I think that using a named variable `my $regex = $args->regex` is the clearest solution here. But if you really want to interpolate arbitrary expressions into a string, you can use a trick: you can interpolate arrays `@foo`, thus also an array dereference `@{ ... }`. Then:

```perl
next unless /@{[ $args->regex ]}/;
```

Comment: `/${\ $args->regex }/` also works. If the method call happened to behave differently in list and scalar context then choosing which one to use becomes more important.